# Which is a statistic, $T(X)$ or $T$?

Tags: terminology

This is a terminology question.

Is $T(X)$ or $T$ a statistic? $X$ is a random variable, and $T$ is a measurable mapping.

I ask this because, I want to know how to say the distribution of $T(X)$ completely in words.
$T(X)$ is the composition of  $T$ and the random variable $X$, and i call the distribution of $T(X)$  the distribution of the composition of $T$ and random variable $X$. But can we simplify the term to be the distribution of the statistic? That leads to whether  $T$ or $T(X)$ should be called a statistic. thanks.

Comment: Is it really an either-or issue? Why could you not call $T$ (which is not a random variable) the statistic and still refer to the distribution of $T(X)$ (which is not a statistic)?

Comment: Do you call the distribution of $T(X)$ the distribution of the statistic? How do you call the distribution of $T(X)$ completely in words?

Comment: I think it would depend on the context. In most situations it is perfectly clear and implicitly understood what $X$ is, so nobody thinks twice about calling both $T$ and $T(X)$ (as well as a realization $T(x)$, for that matter) a "statistic." But if, say, I were comparing the distribution of $T(X)$ when $X$ is a sample with replacement to $T(X)$ when $X$ is a sample without replacement, I would have to be much more careful with the terminology.

Comment: Yes, I am considering the last cases.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, a statistic is a function of the sample. $T(X)$ emphasizes that fact. But often, once the understanding is established that $T(X)$ is a random variable, we sometimes write $T$ and just view it as a single draw from its sampling distribution.

Comment: THanks. do you call $T$ or $T(X)$ as a statistic? ($T$ is a measurable mapping, and $X$ is a random variable)

Comment: Both, depending on context. That's what I was trying to say